# Match paren-groups only when not preceded by tab or space

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

My c# regex code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\((.*?)\)");
return regex.Matches(str);
```

...nicely matches all the "paren groups" as in the data block below:

```
(dirty FALSE)
(composite [txtModel])
(view [star2])
(creationIndex 0)
(creationProps )
(instanceNameSpecified FALSE)
(containsObject nil)
(sName ApplicationWindow)
(txtDynamic FALSE)
(txtSubComposites )
(txtSubObjects )
(txtSubConnections )
```

But the following block of data throws it off the rails:

```
([vog317] of ZZconstant
(dirty FALSE)
(composite [gpGame])
(view [nil])
(creationIndex 1)
(creationProps composite !/gpGame sName Constraint4)
(instanceNameSpecified TRUE)
(containsObject ZZconstant)
(sName NoGo_Track_back_Co)
(description "")
(parameters "")
(languageType Prefix)
(explanation "Some sample text here!")
(salience 1)
(condition "

        (if     (eq ?hoer9_Cl:sName extens)

                then

            (or (eq ?Starry:sName sb405)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb43)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb455)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb48)
            )

        )

")
)
```

Please note the inner-paren group:

```
       (if      (eq ?hoer9_Cl:sName extens)

                then

            (or (eq ?Starry:sName sb405)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb43)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb455)
                (eq ?Starry:sName sb48)
            )

        )
```

That little sub-block of paren-enclosed data should merely be seen as a part of the `(condition` paren-group, and not be matched by the regex pattern. The way to exclude it is for the pattern to see either of the following 2 exceptions:

- Any `(` preceded by a tab or space should be excluded from the match.
- Any `(if` followed by any kind of whitespace should be excluded from the match.

So how can I modify my regex pattern `\((.*?)\)` so that it complies with the above 2 rules? I tried for awhile in [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester), but I'm too much of a beginner with regex to work it out.

Comment: Like this perhaps? `(?<![ \t])\((?!if\s)([^()]*)\)` https://regex101.com/r/zZgEFR/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pattern that you tried, and add lookarounds for the logic in the 2  exceptions listed:

```
(?<![ \t])\((?!if\s)(.*?)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![ \t])` Negative lookbehind <sup>1st point</sup> assert what is directly to the left is not a space or tab
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?!if\s)` Negative lookahead <sup>2nd point</sup> assert what is directly to the right is not `if` and whitespace char
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1** Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `\)` match `)`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b+%5ct%5d%29%5c%28%28%3f!if%5cs%29%28.*%3f%29%5c%29&i=%28%5bvog317%5d+of+ZZconstant%0d%0a%28dirty+FALSE%29%0d%0a%28composite+%5bgpGame%5d%29%0d%0a%28view+%5bnil%5d%29%0d%0a%28creationIndex+1%29%0d%0a%28salience+1%29%0d%0a%28condition+%22%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%28if+++++%28eq+%3fhoer9_Cl%3asName+extens%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++++++then%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++%28or+%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb405%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb43%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb455%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb48%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%22%29%0d%0a%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%28%5bvog317%5d+of+ZZconstant%0d%0a%28dirty+FALSE%29%0d%0a%28composite+%5bgpGame%5d%29%0d%0a%28view+%5bnil%5d%29%0d%0a%28creationIndex+1%29%0d%0a%28condition+%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%28if+++++%28eq+%3fhoer9_Cl%3asName+extens%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++++++then%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++%28or+%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb405%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb43%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb455%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb48%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%22%29%0d%0a%29)

If matching between opening and closing parenthesis can span multiple lines, you could also use a negated character class `[^`:

```
(?<![ \t])\((?!if\s)([^()]*)\)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b+%5ct%5d%29%5c%28%28%3f!if%5cs%29%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5c%29&i=%28%5bvog317%5d+of+ZZconstant%0d%0a%28dirty+FALSE%29%0d%0a%28composite+%5bgpGame%5d%29%0d%0a%28view+%5bnil%5d%29%0d%0a%28creationIndex+1%29%0d%0a%28salience+1%29%0d%0a%28condition+%22%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%28if+++++%28eq+%3fhoer9_Cl%3asName+extens%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++++++then%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++%28or+%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb405%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb43%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb455%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb48%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%22%29%0d%0a%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%28%5bvog317%5d+of+ZZconstant%0d%0a%28dirty+FALSE%29%0d%0a%28composite+%5bgpGame%5d%29%0d%0a%28view+%5bnil%5d%29%0d%0a%28creationIndex+1%29%0d%0a%28condition+%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%28if+++++%28eq+%3fhoer9_Cl%3asName+extens%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++++++then%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++++%28or+%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb405%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb43%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb455%29%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%28eq+%3fStarry%3asName+sb48%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%22%29%0d%0a%29)

Comment: 4th bird: this is very promising but it's missing 1 match:  the one that begins with `(condition` . All the sub-paren-groupings inside that are correctly being ignored, but the outer one needs to be matched. The fact that `(condition` begins on the first character of the line (preceded by a newline) means that it should be matched. Can it be done?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder What exactly should be matched when the parenthesis is the first characterer of the line? Only this part from an opening parentesis till the double quotes? `(condition "` Or a larger match until which part?

Comment: 4th bird: I solved that last little edge case in a different way. Your regex pattern works great. Many thanks!!